# Draw Overlay on Map with Monodroid/Xamarin

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to add an image overlay to my Xamarin/Android map which is in a custom renderer.

I cannot get it to appear on the map. This recipe seems outdated http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/mapview/add_an_overlay_to_a_map/ or I am just missing the Android.GoogleMaps.Overlay class somehow.

```
public class MapContentPageRenderer: PageRenderer
    {
        Android.Views.View _view;
        private GoogleMap _map;
        private MapFragment _mapFragment;
        private LatLng _initLatLng;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var page = e.NewElement as MapContentPage;
            var activity = this.Context as Activity;

            if (activity != null)
            {
                _view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapLayout, this, false);
                AddView(_view);
                if (page != null) _initLatLng = new LatLng(page.InitLat, page.InitLng);
                InitMapFragment(activity);
            }
            SetupMapIfNeeded();
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            var msw = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(r - l, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
            var msh = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(b - t, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
            if (_view == null) return;
            _view.Measure(msw, msh);
            _view.Layout(0, 0, r - l, b - t);
        }

        private void InitMapFragment(Activity activity)
        {
            var cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().Target(_initLatLng).Zoom(14.0f).Build();
            _mapFragment = activity.FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("mapWithOverlay") as MapFragment;
            if (_mapFragment != null) return;
            var mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions()
                .InvokeMapType(GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal)
                .InvokeRotateGesturesEnabled(false)
                .InvokeZoomControlsEnabled(false)
                .InvokeCamera(cameraPosition)
                .InvokeCompassEnabled(true);

            var fragTx = activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            _mapFragment = MapFragment.NewInstance(mapOptions);

            fragTx.Add(Resource.Id.mapWithOverlay, _mapFragment, "mapWithOverlay");
            fragTx.Commit();
        }

        private void SetupMapIfNeeded()
        {
            if (_map != null) return;
            _map = _mapFragment.Map;
            if (_map == null) return;
            ZoomToPosition();

            var mapOverlay = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .Position(_initLatLng, 150, 200)
                .InvokeImage(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon));
            _map.AddGroundOverlay(mapOverlay);
        }

        private void ZoomToPosition()
        {
            var cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(_initLatLng, 15);

            _map.MoveCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just curious, what is hacky about checking for nulls?  Its trying to avoid doing work that's already been completed?

Comment: To me it seems weird that in the current approach I cannot reliably tell when the map is created. I think there must be a solution that can implement `OnMapLoadedCallback` or something. I am pretty new to android and dont have anything against checking for `null` values just if I have one method called `InitMapFragment` I kind of expect to have a fully initialized map afterwards but based on what ive read you cannot tell when `fragTx.Commit` has finished.

Answer (score 0):

**Android.GoogleMaps.Overlay** is **deprecated**.

Being so you **should not** attempt to use this as the example in the [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/mapview/add_an_overlay_to_a_map/) you posted is **out-of-date**.

Instead you should use a **GroundOverlay** or a **TileOverlay** for **Android** **GoogleMaps**, or one of the other **overlays** that are applicable depending on what you are trying to achieve.

**Update 1**:-

Here is an example that creates a custom **GroundOverlay** of:-

- 100 x 100 pixels
- draws a red semi-transparent circle
- and then some yellow text displaying '18' within it

`cobjGoogleMap` would be your map reference of type **GoogleMap**, already previously defined and referenced.

Like in the reference [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/mapview/add_an_overlay_to_a_map/) that you had, it creates a **Canvas** and shows how to draw a couple things on this canvas, prior to adding this to the map.  Hopefully this should set you on the right path to creating your custom drawn overlays?

```
private GroundOverlay cobjGroundOverlay = null;

private void AddMyCustomDrawnOverlayToMap()
{
    LatLng objMapPosition = new LatLng(51, -1.1);
    int intWidth = 100;
    int intHeight = 100;
    //
    using (Bitmap objBitmap = GenerateMyCustomDrawnOverlay(intWidth, intHeight))
    {
        using (Android.Gms.Maps.Model.BitmapDescriptor objBitmapDescriptor = Android.Gms.Maps.Model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBitmap(objBitmap))
        {
            GroundOverlayOptions objGroundOverlayOptions = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .Position(objMapPosition, intWidth, intHeight)
                .InvokeImage(objBitmapDescriptor);
            //
            cobjGroundOverlay = cobjGoogleMap.AddGroundOverlay(objGroundOverlayOptions);
        }
    }
    //
    // Move the camera to the position where we added the new ground overlay:-
    CameraUpdate objCameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(objMapPosition, 17);
    cobjGoogleMap.MoveCamera(objCameraUpdate);
}


private Bitmap GenerateMyCustomDrawnOverlay(int pintWidth, int pintHeight)
{
    // Create your custom overlay Bitmap using a Canvas object:-
    //
    var objPaint = new global::Android.Graphics.Paint();
    objPaint.AntiAlias = true;
    objPaint.Color = global::Android.Graphics.Color.Red;
    objPaint.Alpha = 150;
    //
    var objPaint2 = new global::Android.Graphics.Paint();
    objPaint2.AntiAlias = true;
    objPaint2.Color = global::Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow;
    objPaint2.TextSize = 90;
    objPaint2.Alpha = 255;
    //
    Bitmap objBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(pintWidth, pintHeight, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
    Canvas objCanvas = new Canvas(objBitmap);
    //
    int intHalfWidth = pintWidth / 2;
    int intHalfHeight = pintHeight / 2;
    //
    // Draw a circle (red / semi-transparent):-
    objCanvas.DrawRoundRect(new global::Android.Graphics.RectF(0, 0, (float)pintWidth, (float)pintHeight), intHalfWidth, intHalfHeight, objPaint);
    //
    // Draw some text, although your probably want to do MeasureText etc in order to center things properly:-
    objCanvas.DrawText("18", 0, 80, objPaint2);
    //
    // Return the bitmap that will be used:-
    return objBitmap;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer (See *Update 1*) with an example of creating and adding a **GroundOverlay** to better illustrate how to do this.